# Is $\{x\}$ a neighbourhood of $x$?

Tags: general-topology

According to Wikipedia: a neighbourhood of a point $x\in S$ is a set $U=\{y\in S|\exists\varepsilon>0:\|x-y\|<\varepsilon\}$. My question is: is $\{x\}$ a neighbouthood of $x$ (probably not, given how open sets are usually defined??), or is it required that the "radius" is greater than 0?

Comment: In the definition you provide (there are several possible ones), you say "$\varepsilon > 0$".

Comment: One point is not the neighbourhood of itself.

Comment: @mrf: Yes but $\|x-y\|<\varepsilon$, i.e. could be $0$.

Comment: @Amateur it can be, depending on the metric (or more generally, the topology).

Comment: You misread the definition: $x$ is included in the neighbourhood, but it usually doesn't consist of $x$ alone.

Comment: Actually, the definition as given is not correct. $U$ would be the entire space.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: as an example, let's consider $R^n$ with the usual euclidean distance.

Comment: That example does not change the fact that the given definition has $U$ to be the entire space. Could you provide a link to the page where you found it?

Comment: The $\exists$ is misplaced, but it's obvious what is meant.

Comment: @mrf if you place it differently, you will end up with the definition of a ball around $x$. This is usually not the same as a neighborhood of $x$ (or even an open neighborhood of $x$).

Comment: Many books define open neighbourhoods as balls. Usage varies a lot.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft:  Considering your first comment, can we think of trivial metric space? Thanks.

Comment: @BabakS. Yes, that is the typical example of one where any point is an open neighborhood of itself.

Comment: Isn't a neighbourhood of x usually defined as any open set that contains x?

Comment: What makes it confusing for me is the definition of an open set as the set $S$ where every point in $S$ has a neighbourhood lying in $S$ (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OpenSet.html). If $\{x\}$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ then how do we define a closed set??

Comment: Any open set containing our point 'x' is a neighborhood of x. Don't confuse with the real life meaning of 'neighborhoods'. It has no connection with saying that points in a neighborhood of x are closer to x or things like that. Even the whole space itself is a neighborhood of any point!

Comment: @JansonA.J I understand that. So, is $\{x\}$ an open set? (it is if we say a neighbourhood can be only the point itself, right?)

Comment: Whether $\{x\}$ is an open set depends on the metric. If all singletons are open, then the metric is equivalent to the discrete metric.

Comment: That depend on our topology. I think you're studying metric spaces only. If you don't know general topology it doesn't matter. Actually by a topology we mean we first set the open sets. I mean we just define that these are the open sets and do maths on that. So you can define a topology on a set in which one particular singleton set is open another one is not open, like that.. So {a} is open in your topology iff {a} is a neighborhood of a. As other people have already mentioned, there is a topology called discrete topo. in which all singleton sets are open. => {x} is a nbd of x for all x..!:)

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out above, the definition of a neighbourhood you have mentioned is not correct. It should be that $U$ is a neighbourhood of a point $x$ if $\exists \epsilon > 0$ such that $V:=\{y\in S\mid\|x-y\|<\varepsilon\}\subseteq U $

But now to answer your question. That being 'Is $\{x\}$ a neighbouthood of $x$?'

Well, that does depend on the space you are working with.

If $S =\mathbb{R}$ then no.
If $S = \mathbb{N}$ then yes!

Can you see why? (Here the Euclidean metric is being used).

Comment: Could we say my definition is something like the "minimum neighbourhood"?

Comment: @user1377000 No, your definition is just incorrect. It is asking for all points that have finite distance from $x$.

Comment: You should probably mention the metrics you put on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ to get the conclusions (there are metrics where either is incorrect).

Comment: Yes, thanks for your comment Tobias. I did not want to overcomplicate it for the user. To clarify, the Euclidean metric is being used.

Comment: @jonwilson: " No, your definition is just incorrect": thanks, that makes sense. "If $S=R$ then no": can't we always choose $V=\{x\}$? then the choice of $\varepsilon$ doesn't really matter...

Comment: @user1377000 you can't just choose $V$ freely. It has to have the form given, which depends on $\varepsilon$. And usually, you can't get $\{x\}$ with any such choice.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am still confused: if $S=R$ and $x=2$ what's stopping us from defining $U=\{2\}$ and $\epsilon=3$, so $V=[2,5)\cup \{2\}=\{2\}$

Comment: @user1377000 The first thing you write after $V =$ is not what $V$ would be, and that thing is not equal to $\{2\}$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft $V=[2,5)$ if we use $\|x-y\|=abs(x-y)$. And I actually meant $\cap$, sorry for misspelling.

Comment: @user1377000 No, $V = (-1,5)$, and I don't see why you would take an intersection.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding to @Tobias's neat comment the answer may depend on mthe metric you consider for the space. Indeed, if we consider the following meter $$d(a,b)= \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            1 & a\neq b \\
            0 & a=b
        \end{array}
    \right.$$ then we may have $\mathcal{B}(x)=\{x\},~~~x\in X$. For example, $$S(x,0.5)=\{x\}$$ in which $S(x,\delta)=\{x: d(x,r)<\delta\}$ is the common known set as open ball. Overall, with this meter we have $$S(x,\delta)= \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            X & \delta>1 \\
            \{x\} & \delta\leq0
        \end{array}
    \right.$$

Comment: $\small +1\quad \ddot\smile$

Comment: + 1 $\quad$  : - )